# Using Jinja filter with two variables in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to get a random host in a group that contains a list of IP's.  We are running into some issues as our group name uses a variable, but the line is already in `{{`'s due to the Jinja `random` call.

```
- hosts: "{{ {{ env }}_as_group | random }}"

ERROR! template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '{'. String: {{ {{ env }}_as_group | random }}
```

The env variable is passed into the playbook on execution  with `ansible-playbook "-e env=stage" myplaybook.yml`

Looking around online, most people solve this with `vars[env]`, however that doesnt seem to quite work for us -

```
- hosts: "{{ vars[env]_as_group | random }}"

ERROR! template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '_as_group'. String: {{ tag_aws_autoscaling_groupName_[ env ]_as_group | random }}
```

If I make it `- hosts: "{{ stage_as_group | random }}"`, it works as expected.

How can I set the host to pull a random value in the group `{{ env }}_as_group`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ansible, [*moustache should not be stacked*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names).

So you should use the proper Jinja [concatenation operator](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators): `~`.
Ending with:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ vars[env ~ '_as_group'] | random }}"
```

---

This said it is not totally clear to me what `stage_as_group` really is: is it a list or a hosts group?
If this is a group in you inventory, this won't work because `random` works on a sequence, and a host group is a string, not a sequence.

For that use case, you probably want this instead:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ groups[env ~ '_as_group'] | random }}"
```